# How do I send keyboard commands like (Control) + (1) to the browser using Ruby and FireWatir?

Tags: ruby, watir, firewatir, browser-automation

I am using FireWatir to test a web app and I need to send CTRL + 1 to open up a connection to plugin text "LTN 123456" and send CTRL +2 to close the connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that you forget firewatir gem and use [watir-webdriver](https://rubygems.org/gems/watir-webdriver) gem (it drives Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer). The API is probably 99% the same. It also has good [send_keys](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/keys.rb) implementation.

Comment: Do you know of any good tutorials or places to go where I can see what all can be done with watir-webdriver?

Comment: Have a look at this blog post about sending special keys in watir-webdriver http://watirmelon.com/2011/07/19/sending-special-keys-to-watir-webdriver/